Overlap of wave functions in Franck-Condon principle
I was revisiting the Franck-Condon-principle and was wondering about one thing.
In the Franck-Condon principle, it is stated that if an electronic transition happens, the vibrational wave functions have to be compatible, because the internuclear distance remains relatively the same. The transition is a vertical one.

However, I was wondering the following: Do the vibrational wave functions taking part in the transitions only need to be similar exactly at the internuclear distance R(eq), or have to be overall similar? In the diagram for example, the v”=0 wave function has a maximum at R(eq), and at this equilibrium distance, v’=4 and v’=6 have a maximum roughly at this same position. However, v’=4 has less nodes and seems “overall” (over all R) more similar to v”=0 than v’=6 is similar to v”=0.
So my question is: Does the excited state vibrational wave function only be similar to the ground state wave function at exactly the R(eq) where the transition happens (have a maximum at this position), or be similar “overall” around the R(eq) and R around it?

All that is needed is that the wavefunctions overlap. If they only do a little then FC factor is small and vice versa. Its the area under the curve of the product that matters, $| \int \psi_i\psi_fdx |^2$ for initial $i$ and final $f$ states. At the time of absorption the molecule can be at any position determined by the probability given by the wavefunction. As you can see the displacement between electronic states is important as to which levels have biggest FC but this is accounted for in the wavefunctions anyway.

All that is needed is that the wavefunctions overlap. If they only do a little then FC factor is small and vice versa. Its the area under the curve of the product that matters, $| \int \psi_i(x)\psi_f(x-q_0)dx |^2$ for initial $i$ and final $f$ states. At the time of absorption the molecule can be at any position determined by the probability given by the wavefunction. As you can see the displacement between electronic states is important as to which levels have biggest FC but this is accounted for in the wavefunctions anyway. When the displacement is slight only low quantum numbers v' have large FC, when displacement is large, larger v' are present with greater FC's than those with smaller v'.
I found an old picture showing this


So that would mean that the phase of the wavefunctions does not matter, as long as extrema of wavefunctions are at the same distance? And the wavefunctions in general have to overlap well, not only at the internuclear distance of the transition

the complex conjugate takes care of the phase. As you can see its the whole wavefunction overlap that matters.

Okay true that makes sense. But if only the absolute product matters, why would it be small for 0-20? I mean there are many maxima (but also zero points) so why would the overlap then be small, sorry if I’m asking too much

If you look at the v=0 (blue) curve , then at the other you will see that this oscillates plus and minus so the overlap is small, positive cancels negative, also of course a lot of the v=0 is also v small. The integral extends over all x values.

Why does positive cancel negative if we take the product of both functions at every x value and square it? I would assume that if we multiply the blue function at every x with the oscillating function (which has lots of maxima and minima) then every resultant value should be quite big, if I don't understand this wrong

the product is taken then summed (i.e. integrated) then squared.

So the phase is relevant then I thought it is not. If I understand the phase is just the sign of the function, or do you mean by phase the time dependency of the functions, as these would indeed cancel. So what you mean is that the time dependent phase doesn't matter, and because we take a product of the functions, there are positive and negative maxima which cancel due to integration?

There is no time dependence here. The phase as you call it is removed as the function is $\int \psi^*\psi dx$ where the * indicates the complex conjugate so the product is always real number

Oh sorry I did not know that the stationary vibrational functions were complex

they are not but the complex conjugate is always present in any integral as in some cases the wf may be complex and the result must always be 'real'.

Okay thanks now it’s clear
